# How to display a modal when an option is selected using TreeSelect component in antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying display a Modal which contains a form every time an option is selected using TreeSelect component

I'm not sure what to put in onSelect since the Modal is in another file..

```js
<TreeSelect onSelect="" {...tProps} treeDefaultExpandAll />
```

```js
const tProps = {
            style: {width: 300,},
            treeData,
            value: this.state.value,
            onChange: this.onChange,
            treeCheckable: true,
            showCheckedStrategy: SHOW_PARENT,
            searchPlaceholder: 'Please select',
          };
```

```js
 const treeData = [{
        title: 'User1',
        value: '0-0',
        key: '0-0',
    }, {
        title: 'User2',
        value: '0-1',
        key: '0-1',
        }];
```

Comment: If your modal has to stay in that other file, then I would suggest finding their closest shared parent and passing down a function from there to your `TreeSelect` that will allow you to open the modal.